# What's the name of this vertical tab-like menu control?

Tags: menu, tabs, page-control

I've been trying to recreate this sort of component in JavaFX for a while. The thing is, it looks like a ListBox yet each item functions like a tab. In web design, I'd simply call this a "navigation panel" or something like that.

Here's an example of it from someone's Dribbble, it's the part on the left that controls what's being shown on the right.

[image: Example of a Dribbble user page]

I've seen these types of menus in accordions and all sorts. I just don't know what to call them other than listboxes, menus etc.

So, is the real name of this component a listbox or is it something else?

Comment: These are called vertical tabs

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Thanks for the reply, @user1796650

Comment: @CodeMaverick - off-topic yet I still got an answer. If someone posted it as an answer, I'd accept it and move on. I did search for the best-related section of stackexchange to post this and this seemed to kind of be the best one. I couldn't find a GUI one.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because you are simply asking what something is called. That isn't really what this site is for. Check out [on-topic](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for what you can ask here.

Comment: Posted it as answer, so that you can move on..:)

Answer (score 0):

These are called vertical tabs.

Answer (score 0):

With the shown context, this is called a Message List in some systems. "Vertical tabs" tend to be simpler, with just a label.